# Overloading an operator to return areas

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, operators, overloading

I'm trying to overload 2 operators. I want to overload the '*' operator to return the area of two intersected rectangles. Then, I'm trying to overload the '+' operator to find the sum of the areas of the rectangles subtracted by the intersected area.

I tried to overload the '*' operator using a friend function, but it says there's too many parameters. Is there anyway to get around this or another way to do this?

point.h

```
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

class Point 
{
    int x;
    int y;

public:

    Point(int = 0, int = 0);
    int getX();
    int getY();
    void setX(int);
    void setY(int);

};

#endif
```

point.cpp

```
#include "point.h"


Point::Point(int xcoor, int ycoor) 
{
    x = xcoor;
    y = ycoor;
}

int Point::getX()
{
    return x;
}

int Point::getY() 
{
    return y;
}

void Point::setX(int xcoor) 
{
    x = xcoor;

}

void Point::setY(int ycoor) 
{
    y = ycoor;
}
```

rectangletestdriver.h

```
#ifndef RECTANGLETESTDRIVER_H
#define RECTANGLETESTDRIVER_H
#include "shape.h"
#include "point.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Rectangles : public Shape
{
public:
    int x1;
    int y1;

    int x2;
    int y2;

    Rectangles();
    Rectangles(Point, Point);

    Point point;

    int getX1(Point _point);
    int getY1(Point _point);

    int getX2(Point _point);
    int getY2(Point _point);

    int getWidth(Point _point1, Point _point2);
    int getHeight(Point _point1, Point _point2);

    double computeArea(Point _point1, Point _point2);

    bool overlap(Rectangles _rectangle1, Rectangles _rectangle2, Point _point1, Point _point2, Point _point3, Point _point4);

    double intersectedArea(Rectangles _rectangle1, Rectangles _rectangle2, Point _point1, Point _point2, Point _point3, Point _point4);

    friend double operator+ (const Rectangles& r, const Point _point1, const Point _point2);
};

#endif
```

rectangletestdriver.cpp

```
#include "rectangletestdriver.h"
#include "point.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


Rectangles::Rectangles()
{
}

Rectangles::Rectangles(Point _point1, Point _point2)
{
    int x1 = _point1.getX();
    int y1 = _point1.getY();

    int x2 = _point2.getX();
    int y2 = _point2.getY();
}

int Rectangles::getX1(Point _point1)
{
    return _point1.getX();
}

int Rectangles::getY1(Point _point1)
{
    return  _point1.getY();
}

int Rectangles::getX2(Point _point2)
{
    return _point2.getX();
}

int Rectangles::getY2(Point _point2)
{
    return _point2.getY();
}

int Rectangles::getWidth(Point _point1, Point _point2)
{
    return _point2.getX() - _point1.getX();
}

int Rectangles::getHeight(Point _point1, Point _point2)
{
    return _point2.getY() - _point1.getY();
}

double Rectangles::computeArea(Point _point1, Point _point2)
{
    double area = (this->getHeight(_point1, _point2) * 2) + (this->getWidth(_point1, _point2) * 2);
    return area;
}


bool Rectangles::overlap(Rectangles _rectangle1, Rectangles _rectangle2, Point _point1, Point _point2, Point _point3, Point _point4)
{
    if ((_rectangle1.getX1(_point1) >= _rectangle2.getX2(_point4) || _rectangle2.getX1(_point3) >= _rectangle1.getX2(_point2)) && (_rectangle1.getY1(_point1) <= _rectangle2.getY2(_point4) || _rectangle2.getY1(_point3) <= _rectangle1.getY2(_point2)))
    {
        cout << "no overlap" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "overlap" << endl;
    }
}

double Rectangles::intersectedArea(Rectangles _rectangle1, Rectangles _rectangle2, Point _point1, Point _point2, Point _point3, Point _point4)
{
    int x_dist = min(_rectangle1.getX2(_point2), _rectangle2.getX2(_point4)) - max(_rectangle1.getX1(_point1), _rectangle2.getX1(_point3));
    int y_dist = min(_rectangle1.getY2(_point2), _rectangle2.getY2(_point4)) - max(_rectangle1.getY1(_point1), _rectangle2.getY1(_point3));

    int area;
    area = x_dist * y_dist;

    return area;
}


double operator+(const Rectangles& r, const Point _point1, const Point _point2)
{
    Rectangles rectangles;
    rectangles.computeArea(_point1, _point2) = this->computeArea + rectangles.computeArea(_point1, _point2)
}
```

Comment: `operator+` takes three arguments? Can you give an example of how you imagine a call to that looking?

Comment: Before talking about operator overloading, have you realized what your `getX1`, `getX2`, `getY1`, `getY2` do?

Comment: Since when has the area of the intersection of two rectangles been expressed as the product of those rectangles? Generally, in C++, operator overloading is expected to allow expressions that make sense to mere mortals.   And writing `rectangle1*rectangle2` to get the area of intersection of those two rectangles is obfuscation.   An more comprehensible approach for humans, would be obtain the shape representing the intersection  of the rectangles, and calculate the area of that shape.  e.g. `rect1.Intersection(rect2).Area()`

Answer (score 1):

Think about your function signature.

```
double operator+(const Rectangles& r, const Point _point1, const Point _point2)
```

What are the arguments in your expression? You will use the operator overload like this:

```
Rectangles r1, r2;
...
auto overlap = r1+r2;
```

So the only sensible `operator+` cannot take 3 variables, it must only take 2. Those 2 variables must be all you need to do the operation. Eg.

```
double operator+(const Rectangles& r1, const Rectangles& r2);
```

---

Furthermore, in your friend function (which is not a class member) you do this:

```
this->computeArea
```

What is `this` here? You are not in a member function, so there is no `this`.

---

A final note on design, why do you need the `operator+` to be a friend? What is the union of 2 shapes? It is:

Area(r1) + Area(r2) - Area(Intersection(r1, r2))

Each of these functions are likely publicly available in your shape interface, so an `operator+` that is not a friend and looks like this would do:

```
double operator+(const Shape& s1, const Shape& s2) {
    return s1.area() + s2.area() + intersection(s1, s2).area();
}
```

Comment: And even if you were in a member function and could write `this->computeArea`, `rectangles.ComputeArea(_point1, _point2)` is a prvalue and can't be assigned to.

Comment: @NathanPierson, yeah, there are many things wrong with this code.